# How to get display message in Pyscript

Tags: python, pyscripter, pyscript

New in Pyscript, please spare any dumb mistakes.

Wrote a simple rock-paper-scissor game as below and to run through web browser.
It is running fine, but what I need is that in the prompt it asks the user as "Enter r for rock, p for paper and s for scissor:" instead of blank as in the below screenshot.

I tried python.write, but somehow it throws error and not sure how to use it. Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
 <HTML>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
 <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
  <py-script> 
     import random

     gameAttribute = ['rock','paper','scissor']

     count=0
     yourChoice=0
     comChoice=0
     print('==============================================================')
     print('Welcome','Welcome to ROCK-PAPER-SCISSOR game, Come and try your luck!')
     print('==============================================================')
     while(count != 5):
         count += 1
         random_choice = (random.choices(gameAttribute))
         computerMove = random_choice[0]
         #print(random.choice(random_choice))
         yourMove = input('Enter r for rock, p for paper and s for scissor:')
         

         if yourMove == 'r':
             yourMove = 'rock'
         elif yourMove == 'p':
             yourMove = 'paper'
         elif yourMove == 's':
             yourMove ='scissor'
         else:
             print("Choose between the given choice only!")

         print('computer move: {} '.format(computerMove))
         print("Your move:", yourMove)
         if yourMove == computerMove:
             print("It's a tie!\n")
         elif yourMove == 'rock' and computerMove == 'paper':
             comChoice += 1
             print('You lose!\n')
         elif yourMove == 'rock' and computerMove == 'scissor':
             yourChoice += 1
             print('You Win!\n')
         elif yourMove == 'paper' and computerMove == 'rock':
             yourChoice += 1
             print('You Win!\n')
         elif yourMove == 'paper' and computerMove == 'scissor':
             comChoice += 1
             print ('You lose!\n')
         elif yourMove == 'scissor' and computerMove == 'paper':
             yourChoice += 1
             print('you Win!\n')
         elif yourMove == 'scissor' and computerMove == 'rock':
             comChoice += 1
             print('You lose!\n')
         else:
             print('Invalid choice made!, choose between r,s,p only \n')

     print('==============================================================')
     if yourChoice > comChoice:
         print('Congratulations! You have won the game')
     elif comChoice > yourChoice:
         print('You have lost the game.Better luck next time!')
     elif yourChoice == comChoice:
         print('Tough Competition! It is a tie')
     print('==============================================================')
 </py-script> </body>
 </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's more elegant to use a `HTML form` to ask the user for inputs. I just imported `bulma` for nicer elements.
Additionally there is a [bug](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/239) already reported covering you issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- BULMA CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
    
    <!-- PYSCRIPT -->
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env></py-env>

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- UI -->
    <div id="div1" class="container">
        <div class="section">
            <h4 class="title is-4">
                Welcome to ROCK-PAPER-SCISSOR game, Come and try your luck!
            </h4>

            <br>
            <input  id="userInput" 
                    type="text" 
                    class="input is-info" 
                    placeholder="have a guess"></input>
            <br>
            
            <label id="labelMessage" class="tag">Enter r for rock, p for paper and s for scissor:</label>

            <br>

            <button  id="submit-guess-btn"
                        class="button is-primary"
                        type="submit" 
                        pys-onClick="scissorGuess">Make A Guess</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="section">
            <pre id=log></pre>
        </div>
    </div>

<py-script> 
import random

gameAttribute = ['rock','paper','scissor']

count=0
yourChoice=0
comChoice=0
userElement = document.getElementById('userInput')
logElement = document.getElementById('log')

def scissorGuess(*args, **kwargs):
    global count, yourChoice, comChoice, userElement, logElement
    if count < 5:
        count += 1
        random_choice = (random.choices(gameAttribute))
        computerMove = random_choice[0]
        yourMove = userElement.value.strip()

        if yourMove == 'r':
            yourMove = 'rock'
        elif yourMove == 'p':
            yourMove = 'paper'
        elif yourMove == 's':
            yourMove ='scissor'
        else:
            logElement.innerHTML += "{}. Choose between the given choice only!\n".format(yourMove)

        logElement.innerHTML += 'computer move: {}\n'.format(computerMove)
        logElement.innerHTML += "Your move: {}\n".format(yourMove)
        if yourMove == computerMove:
            logElement.innerHTML += "It's a tie!\n"
        elif yourMove == 'rock' and computerMove == 'paper':
            comChoice += 1
            logElement.innerHTML += 'You lose!\n'
        elif yourMove == 'rock' and computerMove == 'scissor':
            yourChoice += 1
            logElement.innerHTML +='You Win!\n'
        elif yourMove == 'paper' and computerMove == 'rock':
            yourChoice += 1
            logElement.innerHTML +='You Win!\n'
        elif yourMove == 'paper' and computerMove == 'scissor':
            comChoice += 1
            logElement.innerHTML +='You lose!\n'
        elif yourMove == 'scissor' and computerMove == 'paper':
            yourChoice += 1
            logElement.innerHTML +='you Win!\n'
        elif yourMove == 'scissor' and computerMove == 'rock':
            comChoice += 1
            logElement.innerHTML +='You lose!\n'
        else:
            logElement.innerHTML += 'Invalid choice made!, choose between r,s,p only \n'

    if yourChoice > comChoice:
        logElement.innerHTML +='Congratulations! You have won the game\n'
    elif comChoice > yourChoice:
        logElement.innerHTML +='You have lost the game.Better luck next time!\n'
    elif yourChoice == comChoice:
        logElement.innerHTML +='Tough Competition! It is a tie\n'
</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Out:

[image: Screenshot]